# NOPs on Multicore ARM A9

Tags: assembly, arm, multicore, timing

I have a dual core ARM A9 based processor that I need to do some pretty particular nanosecond timing with. I plan on using the NOP assembly instruction to achieve this by determining the number of nanoseconds that pass per cycle of the system clock.

I'm wondering if there are any special considerations I should be taking when calling the NOPs when dealing with a dual core ARM processor, as I've only ever had to deal with single core ATMEL and ARM processors. Is the processor going to try to distribute the NOPs across the two cores automatically? Should I be doing my timing calculation for double the system clock speed (667MHz) to account for the two cores? Are there any other special considerations I'm not seeing that may get in my way?

Comment: No, each core runs its own instruction stream. You don't need to double either. You didn't say if you had an OS, or any interrupts enabled. Those things could mess up your timing ;) Also no idea if ARM cpus do clock frequency scaling (power saving).

Comment: What you're trying to do probably isn't tenable. The ARM Cortex-A9 has uses superscalar out-of-order cores with a 8 to 11 stage pipeline. Even without considering external events, it would be very had to calculate out the exact instruction timings if ARM fully documented everything. Instead their documentation says "The complexity of the Cortex-A9 processor makes it impossible to calculate precise timing information manually. The timing of an instruction is often affected by other concurrent instructions, memory system activity, and additional events outside the instruction flow."

Comment: Out of interest, what's the actual nature of the delay? There may be more creative ways to tackle it - one of the coolest things I've seen was some peripheral which needed an exact delay of the order of a couple of hundred bus cycles between operations; it had an extra register in its programming interface which did absolutely nothing, but which took the requisite couple of hundred cycles to return 0 when read :D

Comment: @Notlikethat the nature of the delay is to time a certain signal coming from a digital output on the device itself that the processor is attached to. Which must be done down to nanosecond time in order for it to work the way I need it to. I love that idea though, it's  hilariously clever, and if I wasn't trying to constrain myself to using just the processor itself it would probably be a hoot to try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly, if you run a single program that is not multi-threaded, there is no way for it to be run on both CPUs. It will always run on one CPU (Although you cannot know which one).

Using NOP to calculate timing is really not a good idea, as you have no control on how instructions are issued and executed, especially because Cortex-A9 has several execution units.

Although I do not think this is a very reliable solution, you should at least use a sequence of dependent instructions that have a timing of 1 cycle:

```
ADD r0, r0, r0
ADD r0, r0, r0
...
```

This will help having one instruction per cycle, better than NOP operations, but this will still be an approximation.

Comment: The OP is still going to have to calibrate his delay loop, but making it latency-bound instead of throughput-bound is a good suggestion that should make the effect of adding an instruction to the loop more predictable.  (Being latency-bound probably saves a bit of power, too.  `OR` or `AND` might be even lower power here.  Are there any lowish-complexity but higher-latency instructions?  Maybe a store-forwarding round trip?)

Comment: Indeed, it's rather the whole point of the architectural `nop` instruction that it's allowed to be elided from the instruction stream early and 'execute' in 0 cycles - I don't think Cortex-A9 actually does that, but some high-end cores might.

Comment: This has all been extremely helpful, the answer above is more than enough, I had originally suggested nop simply because of what I had seen in other code trying to perform similar timing. If my math is right, I have about 350 clock cycles in either direction of leeway on the timing, I'm hoping that introducing the ADD r0, r0, r0 concept will keep me as close to proper timing as possible

Comment: @brad With that much wiggle room, it might also be viable to try something like polling the PMU cycle counter - with a bit of care it should be possible to write a loop for that which fits in a single cache line.

Comment: @brad95411 At 667 MHz one cycle is 1.5 nanoseconds long. If you need 1 nanosecond accuracy you don't have any leeway.

Comment: @Ross Ridge, luckily enough, I don't need that level of accuracy, really, each bit in transmission is 1.25 microseconds long +- 600ns. As long as I'm close it should work